# How I can create algorithm create unique or lowest collision sequence with 10 character?

Tags: algorithm, uniqueidentifier

I want to create code like this `zua-qysx-emr` with unique sequence or lowest collision, efficient (some method have ability duplicate many time lead too low performance).

To details: the code is sequence id, it must be unique in 6 months or more. it about can generate 4.000.000 or more per seconds. And It should be random.

Comment: Do you need to do that for some given values? Or you want to just generate a sequence of uids? If the latter - then how do you define uniqueness in this case? Should it be unique for some specific time? Should it be unique for specific instance? Should it be random? A lot of questions, please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The birthday paradox says that if you uniformly sample random elements from a set of n possibilities, then after sampling roughly √(2n) items there’s a 50% chance of getting some item twice. In your case, suppose you generate a unique ID consisting of k English letters. There’s 26 English letters, so there will be 26<sup>k</sup> possible IDs. That means that you’d expect a collision after around approximately 26<sup>k/2</sup> IDs generated, assuming you did nothing at all to prevent duplicates and just generated them randomly.

When generating cryptographic security keys, it’s common to use 256-bit keys because we’d need to generate approximately 2<sup>256/2</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> ≈ 10<sup>39</sup> keys before collisions are likely, and that’s a staggeringly huge number. If you want to match that level of confidence, you could pick keys satisfying

> 26<sup>k</sup> = 2256
>
> k lg 26 = 256
>
> k = 256 / lg 26 ≈ 56

In other words, picking 56 random characters means you’d basically never need to worry about collisions, period.

But perhaps it would be best to use an existing standard (say, UUIDs) rather than rolling your own?